# Identifying the origin of a DLL

Tags: dll, compiler-construction

How do I determine what compiler was used to create a DLL?

I have a DLL - is it possible to find out how the DLL was created (.NET/C++/Labview etc). I don't have the source of the DLL file. I tried checking with decompilers also, but it does not provide me any information of how the DLL was created.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of tools for performing this sort of analysis. Have a look [here](http://sumtips.com/2012/05/detect-identify-exe-compiler-packer.html) for a summary of some popular options (namely PEiD, Exeinfo PE, and Language 2000).