# PHP - Failed to create COM object XXXXOEM.EjecOEM: Access is denied

Tags: php, iis, permissions, com, permission-denied

Yeah, this question is repeated, but, I swear to you that I read every single link on stackoverflow and google and I'm going crazy with this issue.

I tried a lot of things, I going to put some of them here. None of these worked.

**My system:**

- Windows Server 2008
- Using PHP with class COM to call an object that is not from the system, but from a desktop program called Sage Murano (LogicClass)
- IIS (Internet Information Services)

**My php, ubicated in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blahblah\foo.php:**

```
<?php 
ini_set("com.allow_dcom","true");
$conn = new COM("LogicControlOEM.OEM_EjecutaOEM") or die("Error");
?>
```

**I've tried:**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30242444/4315127

Find out the registers, their keys or whatever, and I gave permissions in all folders that contains "EjecutaOEM" to users:

- Administrator
- Everybody
- Anonymous logon
- IUSR_SERVIDOR (IIS)

2. More permissions http://www.figured-it-out.com/figured-out.php?sid=24
3. Then enable 32 bits on IIS https://help.webcontrolcenter.com/kb/a1114/how-to-enable-a-32-bit-application-pool-in-iis-7-dedicated-vps.aspx

Some ideas to try?

Comment: So, to clarify, is the program on the same machine as the IIS and PHP or not?  If it is on the same machine, have you written a simple VBScript program to verify you can create the object?  Something like `set obj = CreateObject("LogicControlOEM.OEM_EjecutaOEM")` followed by `MsgBox TypeName(obj)`

That is the first step to verify it is createable on the machine outside of the IIS and PHP processes.

Comment: Yes, I did, but I didn't think it would work, it also gave me the same error, but now it did not return anything ... I have put the `MsgBox TypeName (obj)` that you told me and it returns the following: OEM_EjecutaOEM ... That's good, right?

Comment: Yes, that's good.  It verifies that the object can be created through COM on the target machine.  Now the problem is clearly in the realm of PHP/IIS configuration. Does your simplified PHP script run ok if run from a command line and not invoked through IIS?  You should be able to manually run php.exe with the script.  Please see this related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678325/class-com-not-found

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson Ok, also in the .vbs I wrote `obj.InicializaOEM 1, "XXX", "XXX", "", "XXX", "XXXXXX"` (this values are ok), and `res = obj.EjecutaOEM("LogicControlGenerP.GenFunctions", "_DC_Traspasos_Almacen")` and this return 0, it will be cause doesn't exists the function name?

Comment: Can't help you with that problem.  I know nothing about that specific component.